# Date format issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, date-format

I am trying to format a date from javascript as follows.

```
var startDate = new Date('Fri Oct 12 2012 10:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');       

   var dateString = startDate.format("ddd MMM dd yyyy"));

    var timeString = startDate.format("h:mm tt"));
```

When running this from my machine i got both date and time string as expected. like 
**`dateString as Fri Oct 12 2012`** and **`timeString as 10:15 AM`**.

But in live server i am getting **`dateString as Fri 1515 12 2012`** and **`timeString as 10:1010 AM`**.  I think the issue is with format of Month and Minute.

The local server is here in India and the live server is in Us. So i am not sure, is it related with the date format in different culture?

What is the best way to format the date string from javascript. Is i am doing the right thing to format date string.

Comment: Can you please show some code to understand actual problem.

Comment: I can not run your code. Firefox 15 says: `TypeError: startDate.format is not a function`

Comment: @VijayVerma  : Actually the date string i am getting from a Telerik control. When i alerted the value , i got like this. thats why i put the value as such. Modified the code part of my question. Pls check it. I have used like this and i am setting those values to some label and is working.

Comment: try mm/dd/yy as format if it works than it means your formatting wrong.

Comment: Are you using javascript on your servers? Are you using nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

By using `startDate.getDate() & startDate.getDay() & startDate.getFullYear()`
view this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp it helps you.By using this date object properties you can get your appropriate result